# Add a parameter to Strapi V4 request header

Tags: amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, devops, strapi

I am using `Strapi V4` as my CMS and using `ECS S3` as the media storage.

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3 as the provider upload plugin.

I am able to upload media assets to the bucket but get **error 403** forbidden when I try to GET the assets from the bucket.
I have done the necessary additions to plugins.js and middlewares.js files.

I am now trying to add a parameter `"x-emc-namespace": "my-bucket-key"` to the request header in the HTTPS call that Strapi API makes to the bucket.

I have tried the Strapi webhooks approach mentioned **[here](https://strapi.io/blog/understanding-the-different-types-categories-of-strapi-hooks)** but that didn't help in adding a parameter to the request header.

So, my question is how to add a parameter in the Strapi v4 request header.

Comment: It's unclear why you have tagged this question with `amazon-ecs`. You mention you are using "ECS S3" but that isn't a thing that exists. ECS and S3 are two completely separate and unrelated AWS services.

Comment: Yes, it's not Amazon ECS, it's Dell ECS https://www.delltechnologies.com/asset/en-us/products/storage/industry-market/h14071-ecs-architectural-guide-wp.pdf